# 403 Forbidden with Nokogiri requests from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to get and parse a url (specifically, a Sirius XM timestamp request) in my Rails (3.2) app, like so:

```
url = "https://www.siriusxm.com/metadata/pdt/en-us/xml/events/timestamp/01-20-21:59:15"    
timestamp_data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

This works fine from my local development environment, but consistently fails with a "403 Forbidden" response when run from Heroku.

Any ideas on what might causing this to fail on the Heroku side when it works locally?  Is there something I can do to gather more information as to why it may be failing?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Nokogiri, it is the open-uri#open() method that throws the exception.
I'm also getting a 403 when trying to open this url from my machine (both in IRB, and from a browser)
I think you just miss some kind of authentication to access it

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was wondering if it was an authentication issue, but if so, I can't figure why it would work from my local dev environment.